# Counting all the odd numbers in a nested list and printing the result in the output

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and we received an assignment wherein we must arbitrarily define a nested list, and then implement code that counts up all the odd numbers in the list and prints the result out to the user. Our lecturer instructed us to use the modulo (%) operator, as well as nested for loops. However that is as far as he has explained to us how to do, and I'm completely stuck even whilst looking up online guides.

```
m = [[12, 7, 23, 32], [18, 9, 6, 30], [4, 21, 98, 72], [62, 38, 15, 2]]
     
oddCount = 0

for x in m:
    if x % 2 != 0:
```

That is the current state of my code. I am painfully aware of how wrong it might be, but with the little information I have on hand that is all I could come up with. It spits out an error, saying that the modulo operator doesn't work if the object is a list or an integer, and for some reason x is of type list despite me not having it defined as a list.

Comment: You are not using a nested loop as you are told to. In `for x in m`, x will iterate over the inner lists. You also should obviously add code behind your `if x % 2 != 0:` statement.

Comment: well... you're not so far away... just note that your list contains lists!  if you do `for x in m:` then `x` will be another list so you need to loop through this list as well!

Comment: It's not advisable to ask assignment solutions in stackoverflow, they are meant to be solved by yourself. I can provide a hint, you can use `type(element)` to check it's type in python, if it's a list, recursively call the function that iterates over the list and computes the odd number sum.

Comment: A tool that will help you in the future is a debugger like [onlinegdb](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_debugger) that can step through your code line-by-line and show you what values your variables hold.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, but since the arrays are nested you need to use a nested for loop to access the array elements and not just the arrays themselves.

```py
for array in m:
    for x in array:
        if x % 2 != 0:
```

And from there just sum up the odd elements.